# Python replace string in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to add a new column tidy_tweet to the existing .csv file which implements the remove_pattern function

```
def remove_pattern(input_txt, pattern):
    r = re.findall(pattern, input_txt)
    for i in r:
        input_txt = re.sub(i, '', input_txt)
    return input_txt
```

I wrote these lines of code

```
data  = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='stockerbot-export.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
data['tidy_tweet'] = np.vectorize(remove_pattern)(data['text'], "@[\w]*")
```

I am getting the following error

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d6e7e950d5b9> in <module>()
----> 1 data['tidy_tweet'] = np.vectorize(remove_pattern)(data['text'], "@[\w]*")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1970             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
   1971 
-> 1972         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
   1973 
   1974     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2049 
   2050             if ufunc.nout == 1:
-> 2051                 res = array(outputs, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
   2052             else:
   2053                 res = tuple([array(x, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=t)

MemoryError:
```

I can't understand the error. Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory, you are running out of memory as you are working with a huge amount of data and doing loop over it. There is a simpler solution give it a try.

```
data['tidy_tweet'] = data['text'].str.replace('@[\w]*', '',regex=True)
```

remove  `regex=True` if you are using older version of pandas i.e. older than `0.23.0`

[documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Example:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind adding an example please ? Thank you.